# Solving gap issue between links, without having to put code in one line

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to fix the gaps that appear between hyperlinked images, without writing the code all in one line?

I want to be able to write it like this:

`<a href="..." ><img src="..."/></a>`

`<a href="..." ><img src="..."/></a>`

`<a href="..." ><img src="..."/></a>`

`<a href="..." ><img src="..."/></a>`

But the only way I can get rid of the gaps is writing it like this:

`<a href="..." ><img src="..."/></a><a href="..." ><img src="..."/></a><a href="..." ><img src="..."/></a>`

Which is really hard to read with my actual image links which are much longer.

Comment: Which editor you are using? Try another editor.

Comment: you could always try to fix this with some css but that is a fix and not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Because anchors and images are inline by default, they are affected by the white space between those elements in your code (the line breaks).

If CSS is really not an option for you here, you can wrap your whitespace in an HTML comment, like so:

```
<a href="..." ><img src="..."/></a><!--

--><a href="..." ><img src="..."/></a><!--

--><a href="..." ><img src="..."/></a><!--

--><a href="..." ><img src="..."/></a>
```

It impacts readability but prevents the browser from rendering the whitespace, thus eliminating the gaps between your images.

If CSS is an option:

```
img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```